# losing quality when resizing with ImageResizer

Tags: c#, image, png, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm using the [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) .net library. It works as expected, but one image messes around. 
I've uploaded the image below. I've already tried some things like `format=jpg&quality=100`, only `width=220`, also different sizes, but it always adds this blurry border around the image.

The original image is a png.

This one is the original image:
[image: This one here is the original]

This one is resized by the ImageResizer:
[image: This one is resized with ImageResizer]

And this one is resized with photoshop:
[image]

**EDIT:**
If you're running into the same issue. Try to set up the [SpeedOrQuality](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/speedorquality) Plugin. I've set it to `speed=3` and the image is sharp again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector graphics require different resampling algorithms than photographs.

[ImageResizer V4 includes higher quality image resampling options](http://imageresizing.net/blog/2015/v4highlights) under the [FastScaling](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/fastscaling) plugin.

For graphics (non-photographic images), I suggest playing with `&f.sharpen=0..100`, `&down.preserve=-5..5`, and `&down.filter=Robidoux`. Make sure `&fastscale=true` and FastScaling is installed.

You can certainly find a good configuration for your rasterized vector art and set up a preset for it. FastScaling is capable of much better resampling than Photoshop - on par with Lightroom, in fact.

Enabling fastscaling alone helps substantially (`?width=200&fastscale=true`):

[image]

Adding sharpening gives a very clear result: (`?width=220&fastscale=true&f.sharpen=100`):

[image]

Visibly crisper than Photoshop:

[image]

Comment: What is the equivalent syntax for the C# API? `instructions["fastscale"]="true"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you save a jpeg, you loose quality (the image is reencoded).
I would recommend using the same quality as the original image was save against, it should give the best results.

Using a higher quality is not recommended as it will artificially try to improve quality, mistaking approximations done by previous encoding for details, resulting in things like the blurry border.

Aside that, usually, one should not use a quality over 95 for jpeg encoding.

Comment: if I understand you right, when I add just `width=220` it should be good? But as you see I used the big image and resized it via imageresizer and the result is bad, then I resized it with photoshop to the same size and you see the result.

Comment: I think imageresizer will use a default value for quality if you omit the parameter. Try using `width=220&speed=0`, as shown in http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/speedorquality . jpeg compression algorithms are different in different software, so it's quite expected to have quality difference between photoshop resizing and the imageresizer one. You should search for encoding parameters in imageresizer.

Comment: Did you set up the speedorquality plugin?

Comment: Also try using a lesser value for quality, e.g. quality=70 or quality=60.

Comment: yeah I did. I think the problem is the low size, cause when i resize it to 1000 then it is sharp like the original

Comment: Speed=4 causes nearest-neighbor resampling to be used. It can cause ugly artifacts; better to use FastScaling's sharpening control.